# Invalid arguments supplied for foreach() in module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php magento 2.1.2

Tags: magento2

I am trying to get a collection of custom link type called customtype along with related and upsell,In admin while click on a product it will throw an error like

> Invalid arguments supplied for foreach() in module-catalog/Model/ProductLink/CollectionProvider.php line-51.

But in the case of related products in my case the below code return an empty array and there is no issue, why this is happening ?

```
public function getRelatedProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasRelatedProducts()) {
        $products = [];
        $collection = $this->getRelatedProductCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $products[] = $product;
        }
        $this->setRelatedProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('related_products');
}
```

Related product collection

```
/**
 * Retrieve collection related product
 *
 * @return \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Link\Product\Collection
 */
public function getRelatedProductCollection()
{
    $collection = $this->getLinkInstance()->useRelatedLinks()->getProductCollection()->setIsStrongMode();
    $collection->setProduct($this);
    return $collection;
}
```

My custom code is below,

```
 public function getCustomtypeProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasCustomtypeProducts()) {
        $products = [];
        $collection = $this->getCustomtypeProductCollection();
        foreach ($collection as $product) {
            $products[] = $product;
        }
        $this->setCustomtypeProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('customtype_products');
}
```

Collection provider

```
public function getCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product, $type)
{
    if (!isset($this->providers[$type])) {
        throw new NoSuchEntityException(__('Collection provider is not registered'));
    }

    $products = $this->providers[$type]->getLinkedProducts($product);
    $converter = $this->converterPool->getConverter($type);
    $output = [];
    foreach ($products as $item) {
        $output[$item->getId()] = $converter->convert($item);
    }
    return $output;
}
```

di.xml

```
 <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\LinkTypeProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="linkTypes" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="alsobought" xsi:type="const">vendor\ProductLink\Model\Catalog\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_ALSOBOUGHT</item>
            <item name="companion" xsi:type="const">vendor\ProductLink\Model\Catalog\Product\Link::LINK_TYPE_COMPANION</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductLink\CollectionProvider">
    <arguments>
        <argument name="providers" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="alsobought" xsi:type="object">vendor\ProductLink\Model\Product\Link\CollectionProvider\Alsobought</item>
            <item name="companion" xsi:type="object">vendor\ProductLink\Model\Product\Link\CollectionProvider\Companionstyles</item>
        </argument>
    </arguments>
</type>
```

Comment: Show full php code, also show getRelatedProductCollection() function

Comment: Have you solve this error ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below code,

```
public function getRelatedProducts()
{
    if (!$this->hasRelatedProducts()) {
        $products = [];
        $collection = $this->getRelatedProductCollection(); 

        if($collection->count()) {
            foreach ($collection as $product) {
                $products[] = $product;
            }
        }

        $this->setRelatedProducts($products);
    }
    return $this->getData('related_products');
}
```

Comment: Still getting same error, do I need to add any dependencies more in di.xml, just look, I edited the code.

Comment: Have you remove var content?

Comment: yes, removed var and cache also cleared.